# AttributeError: 'TraversalDescription' object has no attribute 'evaluator'

Tags: neo4j

Im trying to traversal a graph using

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
G = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
# G is generated here in my program but for space purpose I removed these steps
traverser = G.traversal().evaluator(my_evaluator).traverse(root)
```

I borrowed my_evaluator function from stackoverflow which is

```
def my_evaluator(path):
    # Filter on end node property
    if path.end['value'] == 105:
        return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE
    # Filter on last relationship type
    if path.last_relationship.type.name() == 'edge':
        return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE
    # You can do even more complex things here, like subtraversals.
    return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE
```

When I tried to execute the code I got the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\firas\Desktop\ACO_neo4j.py", line 747, in 
    traverser = G.traversal().evaluator(my_evaluator).traverse(root)
AttributeError: 'TraversalDescription' object has no attribute 'evaluator'

Can you help me in this please. Thanks.

Firas

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a Cypher query to to the same.

The problem here is that the `evaluator` funcion may be borrowed from the native driver by Neo4j guys, the embedded Python driver. So far, there is some limitations on traversing the graph using the `neo4-rest-client` traversals. Because underneath it is using the REST interface, the only way to write a evaluator is by writing a Javascript function, AFAIK.